# Screen session wouldn't detach, now it won't attach

Tags: gnu-screen

I typically log into my Linux box from my Windows laptop using PuTTY and run screen there.  When my corporate overlords decided to update my laptop to Windows 7 my PuTTY sessions have been freezing.  I typically kill the PuTTY session and then either reattach the screen session (if it detached) or issue a "-d -r" if the screen session didn't detach when my PuTTY session froze up.

My problem is that I have a screen session that, at first, refused to detach.  I'd use:

```
screen -d -r 6313.sessionName
```

but the command would just hang there.

I found that in the /var/run/screen// directory were "files" corresponding to each of my screen sessions.  I noticed that the stubborn one had 700 permissions on it while the others (which were detached) had 600 permissions.

So I changed the permissions on that file to 600.  Screen now lists it as "detached".  However when I try to reattach to it the command, once again, just hangs there.

Using

```
ps aux | grep 6313
```

shows the process state as "Ss", which means it's in an interruptable sleep state.  This is no different than any of the other detached screen sessions which show the same process status.

I'm at a loss as to how to recover this session.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Probably won't help now, but when you start a screen session, how do you start it?  I've always used `screen -S <name>` so that every session has a name I know.  That way, when I want to disconnect and reconnect, I can use that name instead of a PID, such as `screen -r <name>` or `screen -dr <name>`

Comment: That's how I start it too.  But a process ID is prefixed to the name.  For example, 6313.mysession

Comment: Do you manually prefix the pid?  You should be able to access it just by referencing `mysession` instead of `pid.mysession`.

Comment: No, screen adds that to my session name automatically.  And yes, I can reference it by using just the session name (as long as the session name is unique).  I usually name my sessions after the host I'm logged into.

Comment: Then, after using `-S` flag, you should be able to reference just the `mysession` with no need for the pid prefix.

Comment: yes, like I said, I can.  I was using the complete name that "screen -ls" returns (which prepends the session id) just in case it made a difference.

Comment: So, you are seeing the same issue even without the pid prefix?

Comment: Yes, either use, with or without the prepended session ID, the command just hangs there and does nothing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7049/discussion-between-phileas-fogg-and-kruug)

Comment: Not sure if this will help recover anything, but you could try deleting your screen socket file (run `screen -ls` to see where socket files are kept on your system), and then regenerate the socket file with `kill -SIGCHLD <pid>`, where `<pid>` is the process ID of your screen session.

Comment: Did you find a solution? Have the same prob right now.

Answer (score 1):

When I use `screen`command, I usually open the socket like this:

```
$ screen -S <SOCKET_NAME>
```

and when I want to attach or reattach I use:

```
$ screen -x <SOCKET_NAME>
```

Comment: As I explained in the first response I already do that.  And screen -x is the "spy" mode.  It doesn't attach to the session like using "-r" does.  And I've tried that too.  Same results.

Comment: @phileasfogg `-x Attach to a not detached screen. (Multi display mode).`

Comment: @phileasfogg Try this: `-D -RR        Do whatever is needed to get a screen session.`

Comment: "-RR" will create a new session with the same name if it's unable to detach the other session.  That's not what I want.  I have several jobs that need to stay running as well as several files I was editing that I don't want to lose the edits.

Comment: @phileasfogg what is the version of the command screen?

Answer (score -1):

To detach a screen session, you should use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.  Then, to reattach the session, use `screen -r <pid>`.  If you want to connect to a screen session that is in use, then you would use `screen -dr <pid>` to first detach, then reattach, the screen session.

Comment: Yes, I've already tried that as I explained above.

Comment: You stated that you were trying to detach it with `screen -d -r 6313.sessionName` but that only works to detach and then reattach.  That's where the confusion came in.  If you wanted to just detach the screen, you wouldn't use the `-r`.

Comment: I was trying to reattach but because "screen -ls" showed it as "attached" I first had to detach it.